# "Col is undefined" quando uso table.rows.add

Tags: jquery-datatables

Estou tentando pegar um json de uma requisição *AJAX* para inseri-lo na tabela porém sempre que executo o *table.rows.add*

Código da Tabela:

```
<table id="datatables" class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>Id</th>
           <th>Uniforme</th>
           <th>Modelo</th>
           <th>Tamanho</th>
           <th>Cor</th>
           <th>Fornecedor</th>
           <th>Contrato</th>
           <th>Quantidade</th>
           <th>Custo</th>
           <th>Localização</th>
           <th class="disabled-sorting text-right">Actions</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="tbody">
       <tr>
           <td>aaaa</td>
           <td>aaaa</td>
           <td>aaaa</td>
           <td>aaaa</td>
           <td>aaaa</td>
           <td>aaaa</td>
           <td>aaaa</td>
           <td>aaaa</td>
           <td>aaaa</td>
           <td>aaaa</td>
           <td class="text-right">
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-simple btn-info btn-icon like"><i class="material-icons">favorite</i></a>
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-simple btn-warning btn-icon edit"><i class="material-icons">dvr</i></a>
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-simple btn-danger btn-icon remove"><i class="material-icons">close</i></a>
           </td>
       </tr>

   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
       <tr>
         <th>Id</th>
         <th>Uniforme</th>
         <th>Modelo</th>
         <th>Tamanho</th>
         <th>Cor</th>
         <th>Fornecedor</th>
         <th>Contrato</th>
         <th>Quantidade</th>
         <th>Custo</th>
         <th>Localização</th>
         <th class="disabled-sorting text-right">Actions</th>
       </tr>
   </tfoot>
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
 $('#datatables').DataTable({
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "lengthMenu": [
            [10, 25, 50, -1],
            [10, 25, 50, "All"]
        ],
        responsive: true,
        language: {
            search: "_INPUT_",
            searchPlaceholder: "Search records",
        },
        columns: [
           { data: 'Id' },
           { data: 'Uniforme' },
           { data: 'Modelo' },
           { data: 'Tamanho' },
           { data: 'Cor' },
           { data: 'Fornecedor' },
           { data: 'Contrato' },
           { data: 'Quantidade' },
           { data: 'Custo' },
           { data: 'Localização' }
         ]

    });

    $.get("http://localhost/infinity/assets/php/list-uniforms.php", function(data){
        uniforms  = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(uniforms);

        table.rows.add(uniforms).draw();

    });
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece quando você tenta passar quantidade diferente de colunas em `columns:` do que realmente existe na tabela.

Para corrigir este problema, simplesmente inclua a última coluna "Actions" em `columns:`:

```
columns: [
  { data: 'Id' },
  { data: 'Uniforme' },
  { data: 'Modelo' },
  { data: 'Tamanho' },
  { data: 'Cor' },
  { data: 'Fornecedor' },
  { data: 'Contrato' },
  { data: 'Quantidade' },
  { data: 'Custo' },
  { data: 'Localização' }, // <-- não esqueça a vírgula aqui
  { data: 'Actions' } // <-- faltou esse aqui
]
```

Comment: Agora deu esse erro: "DataTables warning: table id=datatables - Requested unknown parameter 'Id' for row 1, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4"

Comment: Eu não tinha adicionado o actions porque ele não faz parte do Json, usaria ele apenas para colocar os botões de ação

Comment: @LuhanSalimena Saquei. Vou ver aqui...

Comment: {add_date: "2018-01-24 17:12:48",
amount: "50",
cost: "20",
id: "1",
model: "Manga Comprida",
place: "NIT",
provider_id: "1",
size: "PP",
uniform_type: "Blusa Social",
userid: "fdsfsfs1f",

Comment: Coloquei porém continua o mesmo erro

Comment: @LuhanSalimena Tenta assim: `$('#datatables').DataTable().rows.add(uniforms).draw();`

Comment: @LuhanSalimena Se vc já definiu o "table" antes, não vai adiantar a dica acima ;/... deixa o "table" mesmo... Para arrumar isso, os itens do JSON devem ter o mesmo nome das colunas: "Id", "Uniforme"...

Comment: @LuhanSalimena Tipo: `{"Id": "1", "Uniforme": "Manga Comprida",...}`

Comment: Vou modificar aqui

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72190/discussion-between-dvd-and-luhan-salimena).

Comment: As colunas estão entrando corretamente, porém sempre é alertado esse erro : DataTables warning: table id=datatables - Requested unknown parameter '10' for row 1, column 10. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4